# How can I rename a column in different matrices with a loop method in r?

Tags: r, loops, matrix, rename, variable-assignment

I am trying to rename a column in lots of matrices (the name of the matrices are mydata1, mydata2, mydata3 and so on) with a loop because I have more than 500 matrices.

Every matrix has two columns: Date and Close and I would like to rename the Close column to for example in mydata1 should be Close1, in mydata2 should be  Close2 etc.

I tried this (to simplify the problem I try to write a code only for the first five cases):

```
for( i in 1:5){

colnames(eval(as.symbol(paste("mydata",i,sep=""))))[2] = paste0("Close", i,sep="")

}
```

but it did not work. And unfortunately this attempt

```
for( i in 1:5){

assign(paste("Close", i,sep=""), colnames(eval(as.symbol(paste("mydata",i,sep=""))))[2])

}
```

did not work either. So my question is: *how can I rename a column in different matrices with a loop method in r?*

Comment: use `paste` with `lapply`

Comment: Thx for the hint, it works:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following below

First creating the data

```
mat1           <- matrix(rnorm(12), ncol = 2)
colnames(mat1) <- c('Date', 'Close')
mat2           <- mat1 * 10
matlist        <- list(mat1, mat2)

matlist
#[[1]]
#            Date      Close
#[1,]  1.45771420  0.1559991
#[2,]  0.87375548  1.3003942
#[3,] -0.95295604 -1.1558864
#[4,] -0.03167548  0.2160419
#[5,]  0.11407587  0.8044782
#[6,] -1.05365988 -0.7321157
#
#[[2]]
#            Date      Close
#[1,]  14.5771420   1.559991
#[2,]   8.7375548  13.003942
#[3,]  -9.5295604 -11.558864
#[4,]  -0.3167548   2.160419
#[5,]   1.1407587   8.044782
#[6,] -10.5365988  -7.321157
```

Using `lapply` to rename the 2nd column

```
new_matlist <- lapply(1:length(matlist), function(x) { colnames(matlist[[x]]) = c('Date',paste('Close', x, sep = '')); matlist[[x]]; } )
new_matlist
#[[1]]
#            Date     Close1
#[1,]  1.45771420  0.1559991
#[2,]  0.87375548  1.3003942
#[3,] -0.95295604 -1.1558864
#[4,] -0.03167548  0.2160419
#[5,]  0.11407587  0.8044782
#[6,] -1.05365988 -0.7321157
#
#[[2]]
#            Date     Close2
#[1,]  14.5771420   1.559991
#[2,]   8.7375548  13.003942
#[3,]  -9.5295604 -11.558864
#[4,]  -0.3167548   2.160419
#[5,]   1.1407587   8.044782
#[6,] -10.5365988  -7.321157
```

Comment: Thank you verx much for the detailed example. My question concerned matrices but your solution is good for my problem too:)